# How to force Visual Studio 2008 to warn about missing header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, settings, header

I work as the Mac coder on a c++ application which I share with PC coders who use VS2008. When they make changes to a source file that requires an non-included header file they get no warnings, as most of their headers are in a precompiled header. What setting can they use to have them be warned that they failed to add the required include?

Would make my life easier as GCC requires the includes be actually present.

Comment: you could disable the precompiled header?

Comment: I can't change the way they compile, that would take forever.

Answer (score 2):

Er... Your question as stated is based on an incorrect premise.

All headers in VS compiler are *required* to be included. There's no way around it.

Precompiled headers feature does not affect this general principle it any way. The only difference is that in projects that plan to use precompiled headers the headers are normally included indirectly, through a special *intermediate* header file. Nevertheless, you can't just forget to include some header file, regardless of whether the project is using precompiled headers or not. All headers *must* be included in all cases, directly or indirectly.

A project that's using precompiled headers will compile perfectly fine on any compiler that knows nothing about any precompiled headers at all.

So, the situation you describe simply cannot happen in practice. If it does, they you must be leaving out some important detail about the problem.

Comment: Hmm, the Intel compiler is what they usually use, I was incorrect in thinking it was the VC++ compiler.

Comment: If that is the difference my question I guess is with the Intel compiler options. Either way the problem is that when I compile on Mac I get errors which I can only fix by finding and adding the correct header to the source file; yet they never notice there is something missing.

Comment: `A project that's using precompiled headers will compile perfectly fine on any compiler that knows nothing about any precompiled headers at all.` - That is wrong... if you are using precompiled headers in Visual Studio, you can choose to omit the includes in your header files (you have to include them in your source files regardless and most likely you did not `choose` but forgot to include them) and the project will compile fine but as soon as you turn them off, you will get a ton of errors for not including the headers that _your_ header knows nothing about.

Comment: @Samaursa: I don't understand what you are talking about. You have to include *all* necessary headers in any case, regardless of whether you are using precompiled headers or not. It doesn't matter whether you are including them indirectly through `stdafx.h` or directly into some other source or header file. Regardless, nothing will break, if you switch precompiled headers off (or use a different compiler). Provide an example of what you are talking about, because I don't see it from you comment.

Comment: @AndreyT: `...indirectly through stdafx.h` That is what I meant. I should have been more clear. With PCHs, it is very easy to forget to include the proper headers in _your_ header file (since it is the first header that your `*.cpp` file must include the required headers are implicitly included) and thus if another library uses it, they will obviously get errors if, say, the header they are including uses `std::string` but they failed to include it because the `PCH` included it for them. Again, the problem stems from the rule that the `pch.h` should be the first header in your `*.cpp`.

Comment: @Samaursa: I still don't understand. The `stdafx.h` (or `pch.h`, or whatever you want to call it) still remains included into all your source files that use precompiled headers under VC++. When you switch to another compiler, that another compiler will simply see `stdafx.h` as an ordinary header. It will include everything mentioned in `stdafx.h` in the usual way. Where is the problem?

Comment: @AndreyT: Remains in your source file, correct, but your header is oblivious to it (unless a source using it includes the `stdafx.h` before including the header). The problem surfaces as soon as another project starts interacting with the library that does not have the same PCH or doesn't even use them to begin with. Then when you include the headers of the project that used the PCH, you will start getting errors. If it is still not clear, I can make a quick solution with two projects to see the problem. This is a common problem and I'd like a solution to OP's problem as well.

Comment: And in large scale software, it is very common to see a solution with 30+ projects, all using their own PCHs. Since PCH makes it so easy to add a member variable to your header file without getting an error `undeclared identifier`, it is easy to make the error of not including the proper header (or forward declaring it if it is a pointer) and consequently your other projects fail to compile (which in itself takes time on large scale projects). The build system points this out and in general becomes another distraction that people want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the precompiled headers conditional on a define that is only present on the PC code, or vice versa for the mac code.